# Content Provider: when try to access data in contentResolver,cursor object is null in Android 13

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

I am trying to transfer data between my two apps by using content provider. Under Android 13, content provider  transfer data between two apps. But, In Android 13, cursor object is null in content resolver.so I'm asking for help.  reference codes [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/content-providers-in-android-with-example/)

```
<queries>
    <package android:name="com.example.otherapp" />
</queries>
```

when I added other application package name query in my application, It is OK.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The [Granular media permissions](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13#granular-media-permissions) for Apps targeting Android 13 may help you:

> If your app targets Android 13 or higher and needs to access media files that other apps have created, you must request one or more of the following granular media permissions instead of the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission:

Also refer to: [Storage Permission in Android 13](https://medium.com/@muhammadbilal4074/storage-permission-in-android-13-89372e543864)